# Is it possible to not receive a message from an observable if I'm only using complete: () =>?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables, angular-observable

Just trying to learn more about observables in Angular and while reading the [Angular observable documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables), it says, under the definitions that

"A handler for the execution-complete notification. Delayed values can continue to be delivered to the next handler after execution is complete"

So I was wondering how this works?

**Question** - Does this mean that if I send a "message", it's possible I won't receive it if I only use the option complete: () =>

```js
this.someService.getMessage().subscribe({message => {
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log(message.whatever),
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that if I send a "message", it's possible I won't receive it if I only use the option complete

The `complete` handler is not intended for consuming any messages that get sent. It is only meant to respond when the Observable gets marked complete. Here's how it might be used:

```
this.someService.getMessage().subscribe({
  next: message => console.log(message);
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer was closed'),
});
```

So if the Observable in the example above emitted one message ("hello") before getting marked complete, you'd see:

> hello
>   Observer was closed

Then there's this interesting bit:

> Delayed values can continue to be delivered to the next handler after execution is complete

This basically means that in some (relatively rare) cases, the Observable might get marked complete *before* the last message comes across. That might end up looking like this:

> Observer was closed
>   hello

That would be kind of weird and unexpected, which is why they want to make sure it's mentioned in the documentation, so you consider the possibility in your handlers.

Of course, if you omit the `next` handler like this:

```
this.someService.getMessage().subscribe({
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer was closed'),
});
```

... then you'd just see the following, no matter how many messages get received from this subscription:

> Observer was closed

Comment: @user1186050: It depends entirely on what kind of Observable `getMessage()` returns, and how it relates to those other components. For example, how do you know when "all components have sent their values"? If there's an Observable that's set up to just emit messages sent to your service from other components, perhaps that Observable will never `complete`. Or maybe it will only complete when the service is destroyed.

Comment: Hi Stripling. So should I always use next? The docs say it's 'required' I'm just working on a project and I see a lot of these calls where there is no next, just completes. ex. logging into the site. after it calls to the controller the post method returns and the subscriber just has a () in it and no next.

Comment: @user1186050: Most of the time an observer is more interested in the `next` than the `complete`. But the two handlers have different purposes, so I wouldn't say to "always" use next. Just understand what each one does, and use the right one for your purposes. Often if you know the observable is only going to emit (at most) one value and then complete, I find it useful to call `.toPromise()` and `await` the promise rather than `subscribe` to the observable.

Comment: What about when I log in the user. There is a post method that takes place to the controller. Would I use a next or complete here?

Comment: If you're not expecting any data back from the server apart from the success/failure status, then it doesn't really matter: both the `next` and `complete` will be invoked, within a very short time of each other. If the log-in endpoint returns information about the user that you'll need, use the `next` handler, because that data will be returned as an argument to `next`. `complete` doesn't take any arguments. HTTP requests are also usually good candidates for conversion to promises, if you don't need the more advanced features of observables (like cancellation).